# Is there any way to use rsocket-kotlin-impl in a spring boot project?

Tags: spring, kotlin, rsocket

Is there any way to use [rsocket-kotlin-impl](https://github.com/rsocket/rsocket-kotlin) in a spring boot project? Thanks in advance !

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please can you give us more information about your attempts? See the guidelines of [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to post great questions :) Take a look also to the StackOverflow [tour](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi @gianlucaaguzz ! Thank you. My question was more theoretical because rsocket-kotlin is based on ktor engines. I did try some attempts but they are long gone by now, thank you for the heads up, next time i will try to follow the guidelines and post my attempts. I will  also check tour (i had no clue it existed!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it as a client to make requests out, for example when a request comes through spring webflow.  But there is no nice support for running a rsocket-kotlin server in spring boot to handle incoming requests.